# save more than one pic with different names in sdcard

Tags: android

Im doing a program where u can draw your signature on the phone. Right now it saves one image but I would like to save more than one image since there are more than one customer that needs to sign their package. very thankful for any kind of help.

```
public void save() {


            File sdImageMainDirectory = new File("/sdcard/mySignatures");
            sdImageMainDirectory.mkdirs();

            String nameFile = "newpic";

FileOutputStream out = null;
            try {

            out = new FileOutputStream(sdImageMainDirectory.toString() +"/" + nameFile + ".jpg");

            mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
            try {
                out.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            out=null;
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather obviously, you need to change the filename to something unique for each one.  Numbering them sequentially would work.  Or you let the user enter a name, and validate it for legality.